# get datediff hours in decimal sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, decimal, datediff

i need query to get total hours in decimal value

## this is my query so far:

```
declare @start as time;
declare @end as time;
declare @total as decimal(18, 2);

set @start = '17:00:00'
set @end = '18:30:00'

set @total = datediff(minute, @start, @end)/60

print @total
```

the query give me integer value, although the @total parameter is a decimal.
I don't know how to get the decimal value.

please help me, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Try  /60.0  this will give the precision needed

Comment: Thank you very much sir, the code you gave me works like a charm!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Datediff returns an integer. When you divide that by an integer (60) you get an integer as a result. If you want the result to be a decimal, you need to divide by a decimal (e.g. 60.0) as per comment from @JohnCappelletti

Answer (score 4):

Try divide by 60.0.  This will provide the required precision

An int divided by an int will return an int.  To circumvent this, simply make either the numerator or denominator into a float.

**Example**

```
declare @start as time;
declare @end as time;
declare @total as decimal(18, 2);

set @start = '17:00:00'
set @end = '18:30:00'

set @total = datediff(minute, @start, @end)/60.0

print @total
```

**Returns**

```
1.50
```

Answer (score 0):

DateDiff always return int, so take the DateDiff in minute, and then divide by 60.0. The decimal point is required.

```
set @total = datediff(minute, @start, @end)/60.0
```