# Display decimal points for DateDiff function in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm not familiar with SQL. This might be a formatting issue?

I have an problem of getting the correct values.
So i have 2 datetime, StartDate and EndDate.

E.g.

- Start Date 2017-12-14 15:13:00.000
- EndDate 2017-12-21 00:00:00.000

**Expected results**

The correct answer should be 9.36 but it keeps on giving me 10.
So i'm trying different ways.

Currently getting the days first (9 days using datediff) then get the decimal value (0.36) --> for hours in days

So that i can have 9+0.36 = 9.36

From all the posts that i've read, i have tried the following ways

```
DECLARE @temp AS DECIMAL(10,2) = CAST(DATEDIFF(second, CONVERT(time, @StartDate), CONVERT(time, @ENDDate)) as Decimal(10,2))/86400.0

DECLARE @temp AS DECIMAL(10,2) = DATEDIFF(second, CONVERT(time,@StartDate), CONVERT(time,@EndDate))/3600.0

DECLARE @temp AS Decimal(10,2) = CAST(@StartDate - @EndDate) as Float) * 24.0

DECLARE @temp AS decimal(10,4) = DATEDIFF(ss, @StartDate, @ENDDATE)/3600.0

@temp = CAST(DATEDIFF(minute, CONVERT(time, @StartDate), CONVERT(time, @ENDDate)) as Decimal(18,2))/60
```

Understand that the divisions might not be correct. But the important thing is to get at least a decimal with values not 10.00.

The column in SQL is also (decimal(12,2). Just wondering no matter how i try to divide, the column keeps on returning me 10.00 instead of 9.36.

**Some Post that i referred to:**

[get datediff hours in decimal sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45156749/get-datediff-hours-in-decimal-sql-server)

[TSQL DateDiff to return number of days with 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9524094/tsql-datediff-to-return-number-of-days-with-2-decimal-places)

[DATEDIFF() to just return age with 2 decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077109/datediff-to-just-return-age-with-2-decimal-points)

Seems like a very common issue but i just can't get it to work.

Can anyone help to take a look? Thanks!

Update: Turns out i forgot to put RETURN DECIMAL(10,2). I only put RETURN DECIMAL..

Comment: I think all (or most) of your expressions should do what you want.  How are you showing the results?  Here is a db<>fiddle showing that these do work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=328c6c1e925ed7d030396f2a9b9dc986.  Also, the answer should be 6.37, not 9+.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Actually, i will need to exclude weekends and PH as well. I forgot to mention it above. 
But it’s good to know that this line of code works fine. Just find it weird that it’s not displaying even though the dates are indeed datetime.

Comment: . . That is a very different question.  You should ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. You can run this [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=328c6c1e925ed7d030396f2a9b9dc986) or this code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2017-12-14 15:13:00.000';
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '2017-12-21 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @temp DECIMAL(10,2) = CAST(DATEDIFF(second, @StartDate, @ENDDate) as Decimal(10,2))/86400.0
DECLARE @temp2 DECIMAL(10,2) = DATEDIFF(second, @StartDate, @ENDDate)/86400.0

select @temp, @temp2;
```

So, what simple mistake would cause you to get the results that you are seeing?  There is one:  if you have defined your "date" variables as `date` rather than `datetime`.

I suspect that you have:

```
DECLARE @StartDate date = '2017-12-14 15:13:00.000';
DECLARE @EndDate date = '2017-12-21 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

it works fine

```
DECLARE @t AS DECIMAL(10,2);

set @t= datediff(second,'2017-12-14 15:13:00.000','2017-12-21 00:00:00.000')/(3600.00*24);
select @t
```

so i think your also worked

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2a624a81856375ae3a77584d6c19e156)